# gson - How to create a general data structure from a json string

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have a complex json string as a source and I want to create a data structure 
i.e. ( Map< String,String> that contains several maps) without declaring any type.

So that I can later manipulate it and use toJson and get a string back.

Is there a way to create a general data collection from a json source ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

```
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    Type mapOfStringStringType = new TypeToken<Map<String,String>(){}.getType();
    Map<String,String> resultSet=gson.fromJson(JSONString,mapOfStringStringType);
```